# How to pass complex model from view to controller (with saving some changed data)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a model with complex properties like:

```
public partial class CrmDefinedEntity
{ 
   private List<string> attr1;
   private List<int> attr2;
   private List<CustomType> attr3;
   string txt;
}
```

and I want to change  `attr1` property (change some string members) in view and than save everything in an action.

```
public ActionResult SaveTest(CrmDefinedEntity model)
{
   return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

What is the best approach for that?

Comment: attr1 and attr2 are pretty easy, you can use Checkboxes or a List for those. attr3 is a bit tricky depending on what CustomType is. We would need more code to better assist you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write some html and javascript to iterate through the lists on the page and provide text editor boxes or you could use a telerik mvc control.

Personally, I prefer telerik controls because they are pretty powerful, easy to use and their tech support is pretty good. (Not to mention its free)